# Run batch file when USB drive detected

Tags: windows, usb, windows-registry

How can I configure my PC to execute a batch file every time any USB drive is inserted? I would like to use `regedit`, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned batch file scripting, I'm going to assume a windows platform.  You can write an application that handles these events: [`WM_DEVICECHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480%28VS.85%29.aspx)

I imagine you can have it running in the background as a daemon and have it call your batch file upon the right conditions.